# What action should we take with answers that don't show enough work, but are useful and upvoted?

Tags: discussion, faq

We want answers to show their work, and of course we want answers to be useful. We've now got a fairly clear idea of what our standards are and what we should do with answers that fail on both counts.

Slightly trickier is answers that *are useful* but do not meet our standards for showing their work.

What action should we take with these?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't want useful answers deleted even if they don't show their work perfectly.

For an answer that isn't useful, deletion is fine, but I think we need another way of dealing with useful answers that don't meet the standard of showing their work. I suggest we ask SE for a custom post notice or two that are used just for this purpose, that specifically mention that the post is otherwise good, something like:

> *This answer is useful but is not the kind of answer [we are looking for](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/43) because it does not [show all the steps from the text to the conclusions](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/43)*

or

> *This answer is useful but is not the kind of answer [we are looking for](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/43) because it [contains unsourced factual claims](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/43)*

Comment: Any status on getting these custom post notices?

Comment: I think events may overtake this within the next week. Sorry the cogs are turning slowly but we are getting there I think!