# Should we positively discriminate in favour of all non-Protestant perspectives on BH?

Tags: discussion

It seems to be the case that many of our active contributors hail from Protestant traditions and perspectives. Several folk have expressed concern about this:

- > [I currently believe there is a strong mainstream evangelical Protestant bias here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1505?m=12506712#12506712)
- > [I wonder if it will take an extreme example to help Protestants realize how much bias is allowed here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1505?m=12117326#12117326)
- > [I looked around and sometimes answers seem to be for all Christian groups but other times I saw only Protestant theology](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/coherence-based-genealogical-method-vs-local-text-types-theory/3995#comment7644_3995)
- > [We look like a Christian (Protestant even) site to an outside observer. Given that many of our most active contributors and pro tempore moderators are Protestant Christians, that's not a big surprise. But it is a big concern.](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/friends-we-are-not-christian)

The questions arise:

- whether this is (still) a problem?
  and
- if it is, whether we can help by actively promoting other perspectives here with positive discrimination.

Answer (score 8):

**No, we should not positively discriminate in favour of all non-Protestant perspectives**

---

1. Our site aim to [welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist and other viewpoints as long as they take seriously the process of understanding the Biblical texts](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should not be understood as an aim that we end up with an equal mix of participants of each group<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>. Rather it should be understood that as a site, we are about the '[Biblical texts](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/43)' and not concerned with religious beliefs<sup><sup>2</sup></sup> and traditions *per se*, but only insofar as they intersect with the Biblical texts and their interpretation
2. Protestants are probably highly represented here because of the [doctrine that the Bible contains all knowledge necessary for salvation and holiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura). ***This does not mean that other traditions do not care deeply about the texts and their interpretation***, however there is a strand of Protestantism that elevates the texts above everything else, and a site that is explicitly about the texts and nothing else is likely to be especially attractive to those folk. In other words, Protestants are by and large going to be attracted here ***for the right reasons***: ie that "they take seriously the process of understanding the Biblical texts". Therefore to embark on a policy of discriminating against them just for being Protestant would undermine the foundation of the site.

I'm not at all arguing against promoting the site to particular individuals or groups. I am personally very excited when someone from an unfamiliar perspective starts contributing and saddened if they leave. However ***positive discrimination should not be site policy.*** The correct and well established approach is to continue to affirm that contributions should show enough of their working to make them useful to folk who don't necessarily agree with their conclusions.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> however you choose to delineate groups!</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> or [religiously loaded words](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/900/43)</sub>

Comment: Yes, indeed! Protestants are also 'not afraid' to vociferously air their views without the slightest concern for their audience.....(hmmm). It just so happens that Protestants occupy more Bible schools, and have textual questions regarding what they're studying. The question is valid, and your answer is correct...sometimes we have to remember to 'play nice' with the other children  :>)

Comment: Your #2 is, in my mind, without doubt why there is a leaning of that group as majority participants on this site.

Answer (score 2):

**No, we should not positively discriminate in favor of all non-Protestant perspectives. However, we should be respectful of others' beliefs by speaking descriptively rather than prescriptively about our beliefs.**

1. **We should avoid the fallacy that we can somehow *require* diversity.** We certainly *welcome* diverse perspectives, but what if some questions only have Protestant Christian perspectives? [We can't control](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/870/423) whether or not Jewish, atheist, and other contributors post answers or not. Neither should we expect every OP to find every perspective useful. The key is they we are *respectful* of other perspectives and acknowledge that other users may find them to be useful answers—even if we don't.
2. **It is undesirable to speak *prescriptively* about the text in such a way that it implies norms that are expressed as binding on readers.** The OP can make the exact same points [making it clear](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/912/423) that s/he is talking about him/herself without imposing beliefs upon the reader. As [another user has helpfully pointed out](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/903/423):

   - > This is sometime stated in terms of "descriptive" *versus* "normative", especially in Brevard Childs's well-known [essay on theological commentary](http://int.sagepub.com/content/18/4/432.extract). If something is being *prescribed* for readers of BH.SE, or if the Q&A in some measure is implying *norms* binding on readers here ... [that's a problem](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/892/2215). On the other hand, if a Q&A is *describing* the linguistic, literary, or theological dimensions of the text as it was understood by its authors and reading community in antiquity, then we'll be on safe ground.
3. **Speaking descriptively fosters a diverse community where Christian, Jewish, atheist, and other perspectives actually feel welcomed.** Like it or not, people don't feel welcome when prescriptive language is used. Here's a few examples from different users in chat:

   - > [unfortunately, i feel that i am getting preached at when i write my (science based) questions...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13906945#13906945) [i know those questions, when based on the text are welcome on BH and that atheists like me are theoretically welcome - being preached at does not reflect at -to me, it shows a lack of respect for my beliefs. This site will be great when it evolves to fully embrace these types of questions...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13906995#13906995)
   - > [Telling people what to do with their lives is preaching.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14306971#14306971)
   - > [...the site is turning into something that i find to be intolerable....](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9339615#9339615) [and i'm tired of defending myself against people who reject history and literary criticism....](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9339619#9339619) [i dont care for the direction of the site....](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8807154#8807154) [i fault the influx of a majority of people who thing that every answer must be necessarily Christological and any challenge to that is met with some sort of guffawing....](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8807192#8807192)
   - > [i am walking away from the site, primarily due to still not being convinced that I can contribute any further - I am an Atheist, and the earlier preaching by a few has left a lingering sour taste](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14293380#14293380)
   - > [le sigh. i suppose like most good things, sometimes you have to wade through sewage to find the treasure. i just dont have the stomach for it so i suppose i'll answer again, at some point, when i dont have to worry about someone's personal theology invading it to the point that it becomes nonsensical.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12765989#12765989)
   - > [Preaching, or language that assumes we're all in the same church and follow Jesus, or that asserts things that aren't actually found in the text (or even if found, not supported)... those are problems.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12828476#12828476)
   - [Others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/592/423) have also [expressed their frustration on meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/730/423).

I don't want to see positive discrimination towards a specific religious tradition. But I do want all perspectives to be welcomed, and that will require all of us to bracket our beliefs to some extent and step outside of our comfort zones. Speaking descriptively rather than prescriptively is not a difficult burden  and will help us work toward making this a reality.

Comment: I guess your definition of welcoming all perspectives has some overlap with my definition of positive discrimination.

Comment: Positive discrimination would mean giving minority groups preferential treatment over majority ones. I believe that asking folks to respect others' by not prescribing their beliefs to them is not targeting any specific group. This would be equally expected of Christians, Jews, atheists, and all participants.

Comment: I didn't say it overlapped with *your* definition of positive discrimination. The group you are particularly positively discriminating towards are those who already accept your definitions of 'respect' and 'prescribing their beliefs'.

Comment: @JackDouglas and that group consists of Christians (including Protestants), Jews, and atheists - the groups we explicitly welcome. So by definition, it would not be positive discrimination if they were all held to the same standard. But I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: I think it is positive discrimination towards the secular or traditions of academia.

Comment: I basically agree, Daи, but I also agree there is a danger as @JackDouglas stated, "discrimination towards the secular or traditions of academia," by being too dogmatic on no "doctrine." This site will _forever_ be teetering on a twine over a tempestuous torrent with respect to the balance. But generally not _explicitly_ prescribing is best. Let _the text itself prescribe_ for the reader when valid. It would be hard to not read [my descriptive answer here](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8983/is-romans-117-ambiguous/9005#9005), and walk away without feeling prescribed to.

Comment: @ScottS I just upvoted that answer. That post does not fail this test of speaking descriptively. The text is *often* prescriptive, and that's fine. The goal is to keep in mind it was prescribing something to its original audience in antiquity. The trick is to not *explicitly* conflate the audience of antiquity with the modern reader of the answer. It will happen all the time *implicitly*, and that can't be avoided.

Comment: And ScottS and @JackDouglas there are academic folks in Protestantism as well, so that is a false distinction. The point of your meta post was positive discrimination in favor of non-Protestants. This is not an example of that.

Comment: Respecting others' beliefs by speaking descriptively is not a discrimination issue, it's a behavior issue. Folks from all perspectives can do this, some folks *choose* not to. No one is discriminated against by this sort of guideline any more than saying that it is discrimination for participants to be required to 'show their work'.

Comment: I agree "to not _explicitly_ conflate the audience ... [&] modern reader." I believe for @JackDouglas (at least, for me how I take it) "or traditions of academia" was a descriptor of "secular" (i.e. academia often dismisses the "religious" even when dealing with "religious" texts). He (nor I) would not want to see the site go so far that direction that it loses the ability to express "religious tradition" at all. Also, for _evangelical_ Christians, it actually _is_ discrimination to not let them "preach" the good news. So again, there is no "neutral" point. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) But I think that (not "preaching") is one discrimination that should be in place for this site, because it can overpower the voices of those that do not have such a "tradition" in their religion. And, as we noted, one can do it by just _expounding the text_ on many texts.

Comment: @ScottS I'd love to hear your definition of what 'preaching' means and what standards/metrics could be used to determine when language is 'preachy' vs. <insert word meaning 'not preachy' here>.

Comment: @Scott I really don't like the site being used as a platform for crudely lambasting the other users with someone's views: but I'm almost loath to say so in case Dan quotes me in support of cracking down on anyone who writes anything that isn't couched in secular-PC-speak. The means I suggest for preventing it is to not *define* 'preachy' at all but insist that posts show their work: that has the excellent side-effect of denying egregious offenders a platform. Most cases of crude preaching here get down-voted into oblivion very quickly already, so for me there is not a problem...

Comment: ... what concerns me is that Dan wishes to change the site, to have rules and definitions he can use against popular, upvoted content that does not fit his oft-stated model of what he wants the site to become. A model that in my view would result in a site that most of the current participants including myself would not find particularly useful.

Comment: @Daи In short "preaching" is both exposition and exhortation (in this case as a call to action to change one's behavior). So basically, the 1st person plural, 2nd person sing/plural urging response.

Comment: @ScottS that seems plain as day to me as well, and is a straightforward definition. The thing is, I'll sometimes even tolerate a *little* preaching if surrounded by outstanding exposition. The problem is when folks *primarily* exhort without expounding the text (and show complete ignorance of the historical, linguistic, and literary aspects/context of the text). But I think the 1st person plural/2nd person sing/plural urging response test is a good one, and I agree that being consistent (no preaching) would be the best way forward.

Comment: @ScottS I'd love to see you weigh in [on this question](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1014/423).

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't have a higher score. I thought not being arrogant (Im right you're wrong you should follow my religion) was just good manners. Is there a problem with answering from text not from belief?

Comment: @user4275 as you can see, there are a lot of participants here who want to be free to answer from belief, primarily Christian belief. While [speaking descriptively rather than prescriptively](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/1015/) and [staying on target](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/643/) are simple guidelines to follow, we have some who refuse to do so and receive lots of community support for going far beyond answering the question. It's unfortunate in my opinion (because it chases off some of the perspectives we're missing) - but that's the way it is right now.

Comment: @Daи yea it looks like lots of people answer from religion not text, of course Christian because that's statistics. Since they are allowed to do it and get votes they arenot going to stop, so it becomes a Christian site. Doesn't matter what people say in chat or meta if reality is different. Glad I found out early, anyway. Just saw a profile from a Jew with lots of rep who left becasue of this, sad.