# Please let me go

Tags: support

Can someone tell me how I can cancel my "membership" or "subscription" or whatever to Biblical Hermeneutics?  Or can someone with privileges do it for me?'

I joined a while back.  I got kind of tired of the argumentation I saw.  (I wasn't guiltless here, but I wasn't one of the worst either.)  I asked a question and someone user with privileges didn't like it, so she just deleted the thing.  I got ticked and stopped viewing.  But then I thought, "Well, if I violated their standards, then maybe she was right in what she did.  I'll take a look at their standards."  There were none to be found, not at that time and in any reasonable place, anyway.  So then I got really ticked and left for good.

This was well over a year ago, but to this day I get periodic downvotes and complaints about how things I wrote *over a year ago* don't "meet your standards" or whatever.  These notices are enough of a distraction that not viewing here is not enough anymore.  I want out completely.  Please, someone show some Christian mercy and help me!

And one parting shot: I am a member of several sites on Stack Exchange.  "Biblical Hermeneutics" is the one where I have by far been treated the worst, no contest.  And when you see all the ill-tempered nerds on the other sites, that is saying something!  And I am getting this from a bunch of Bible readers!!!!   Leave me alone, PLEASE!!!!

ADDENDUM: Now that I've calmed down, sorry for any hurt feelings I might have caused(heck -- probably did cause).  I flew off the handle.  Seriously, though, despite the tone in which my request was made, I still have to make the request itself.  For reasons I won't rehearse again, I don't foresee myself contributing to this site in the future, and therefore the various notices I keep seeing and have mentioned already really are a distraction.  So I hope you can keep them away from me. I have followed the instructions for deletion as I understand them, so I trust that this will be taken care of before I see another downvote notice or whatever.  In all sincerity, best wishes for you all and for this site.  Sorry I can't be there to see them realized.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, and best wishes :)

Comment: Besides changing your profile content to confirm the action, did you actually hit the delete button and see the delete timer start?

Comment: @Caleb Changed my profile, did the "please contact us" thing too.  Didn't notice a timer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry you feel that way Bob.

Disassociation [is no longer possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109054/166851), so I'm afraid the only option is to delete your BH account - instructions on how to do that are [in the help centre](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Looking at your profile, I can't see the question that was deleted - do you have a link so I can look at it?

Comment: I didn't tell the whole story.  Some other brave soul with privileges re-wrote it and re-posted it so that it satisfied whoever else had the problem.  Which was nice, and whoever that was has my thanks.  But that wasn't enough to make me want to put up with the original deleter and a few other rather rude individuals as well.  And like I said, it's been well over a year now, and I still get complaints about my old answers and comments.  Somebody on this site needs to learn to give things a rest!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be referencing my recent decision to convert [one of your answers](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/4787/) into [a comment](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/why-did-paul-collect-and-deliver-an-offering-for-the-jerusalem-church/4787#comment23592_4782). I did so because it didn't really answer the question, and it didn't elaborate on any of its assertions. A month before you had posted that answer in 2013, [Caleb had written an excellent explanation of what we are looking for in answers](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/) ([he also elaborated on this much more](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/)). Your answer simply didn't meet those standards, and being over a year later and seeing that it was only attracting downvotes, I converted it to a comment so that others would still see it. I apologize for not linking to the specific meta posts, but I stand by my decision to convert that to a comment.

As far as deleted questions and whatnot, I'm not sure what you are referencing without links. But if my recent conversion of one of your answers to a comment was a factor, I wanted to address that.

Comment: It was a over a year ago.  That's how I see it.  But beyond that, just this one incident wouldn't have made me spout off like that.  I'm not a part of this group anymore and I just don't want to keep seeing downvote notices etc.  Best of luck to everyone on this site.  Good bye.  Please.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you go, but [here are instructions for doing so.](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

Answer (score 2):

Bob -

You have only lost 9 points; if I can confess, I have been marked down ***dozens*** of points in the last 12 months, and in one case, someone knocked down my last ten or fifteen consecutive postings (at one time) as if trying to send me a message to get lost.

But get this: the feedback has helped me to be more "objective" in my responses. That is, one must write with such a style so that if the reader disagrees with you, then you would have to point them to the text and say that they are not disagreeing with you, but with the text (because your explanation was very clear, objective and concise). In other words, when your explanations make "normal and plain" sense, then you let the reader decide for themselves. Again, if they disagree, let them provide the explanation that would make plain sense if explained to your grandmother at the kitchen table.

Please stick around, and take a peek once in a while. It is kind of unfair that one or two individuals on this website should make you feel so down, when there are in fact others who would give you candid feedback with the intent of improving your posts and points. You do not have to be the smartest person to contribute to this website, however you do need to edify others with your knowledge, and the more clear and concise, the better.

Hope to see you around.

Joseph

Comment: First, I still see that I have not been "anonymized".  Oh well.  Second, the downvotes I received had absolutely no constructive criticism, or even unconstructive criticism attached.  I find this utterly unhelpful on any site, and inexcusably rude on a *Biblical* Hermeneutics site.  There is just simply no way to see an unexplained downvote and figure out from that what needs improvement.  Third, again, I don't see myself contributing here in the future, so these notices are simply distracting and annoying.  Fourth, it's been more than a couple of people.  But thanks for your concern.

Comment: @bob.sacamento - Bob, I am just trying to say that I have had it worse than you.

Comment: @bob I've no idea why it's taking so long, but we have no control over it - once the system 'notices' your profile change it will start a countdown (24 hours I think) and then will action the delete. We respect your choice to leave but for the record I vouch for Joseph's answer here - he's met much opposition and responded magnificently and graciously.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I'd also like to mention that votes (whether up or down) are _not intended_ as a feedback signal for you so  much as for other readers on the site. The comment section is the tool designed for feedback. It sounds like you were expecting something of the vote system it wasn't designed for. It's really just a crowd sourced sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Caleb  Again, since I'm still here -- What I said still stands: It is impossible to improve on anything when all you see is an unexplained downvote.  Regardless of the intent of the system, downvoters should be always mindful of this.