# What should we look for in answers about prophecy?

Tags: discussion

In the past, we have defined what we look for in [good answers](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-we-looking-for-in-answers) — for example, answers need to [show their work](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/536/what-does-show-your-work-mean-in-the-context-of-exegesis) and follow [site distinctives](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives).

Recently some [discussion on whether questions about prophetic passages should be on topic have arisen](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/is-interpretation-of-prophecy-on-topic). While it is clear to me that these questions should be on  topic, it may be helpful to provide some more specific and targeted guidelines to users on this specific type of question.

So, what specifically should we look for in good answers **for questions regarding prophecy**? Should they have different criteria than [general answers](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-we-looking-for-in-answers)?

Comment: Historical Interpretation and/or Parallelism sound like two excellent things we should look for in answers to questions about prophetic passages. I would suggest you add these as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

OP asks:

> So, what specifically should we look for in good answers for questions regarding prophecy? Should they have different criteria than general answers?

But there isn't such a thing as "general" answers. **ALL** answers should *answer the question posed*.

My own sense of what this means in practice is [detailed in a previous Q&A](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/886/2215). Essentially, it boils down to this: there should be a sense of *fitness* (i.e., "good fit") between Q and A. And what is appropriate, fitting, commensurate, is determined by the question asked.

Answers should bring the right tools to do the job of *answering* the specific question, whether the text giving rise to the question is "prophetic", "legal", "narrative", "hymnic", "administrative", "proverbial", "genealogical", "historical", "epistolary", "liturgical", or ... whatever!